# First two fields to be separated by _ and rest of the fields as they are

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

```
#CHROM  POS     REF     ALT     ../S101_sorted.bam      ../S102_sorted.bam          ../S105_sorted.bam      ../S107_sorted.bam      ../S113_sorted.bam      ../S114_sorted.bam      ../S115_sorted.bam      ../S
Aradu.A01       296611  T       C       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T/C     T       T/C     T       T       T       T
Aradu.A01       326689  T       C       T/C     T       T       T       T/C     T       T       T       T/C     T/C     T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T/C     T/C     T       T
Aradu.A01       615910  T       G       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T
Aradu.A01       661394  T       A       T       T       T       T       T       T/A     T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T
Aradu.A01       941674  C       T       C       C/T     C       C       C/T     C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C
Aradu.A01       942064  C       T       C/T     C/T     C/T     C/T     C/T     C       C       C/T     C       C/T     C/T     C       C       C/T     C/T     C       C       C       C       C/T     C/T
Aradu.A01       954858  G       A       G/A     G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G       G/A     G       G       G       G
Aradu.A01       1196780 C       A       C/A     C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C       C/A     C       C       C/A     C       C       C       C       C       C
```

I have a file in the above format and I am trying to print the first two columns separated by `_` and rest of the columns as they are. I tried the following `awk` script nut it does not return any output.

```
awk '{if (NR>1) print $1"_"$2; for(i=3;i<NF;i++) printf "\t", $i}' input_file > out_file.
```

Can any one please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

To change the whitespace between the first two columns to an underscore, I suggest `sed`:

```
 sed -e 's/[\t ]\+/_/'
```

And if you were to need to ignore the header line:

```
sed -e '/^#/! s/[\t ]\+/_/'
```

or, for the more general case (header might start with any char; `\t` works only with `gnu sed`)

```
sed -E '1! s/[[:blank:]]+/_/'
```

As to the question about your `awk` code, the first `print`, should likely be a `printf` so as not to have it print an ill timed newline.

Comment: Note that all of `\t`, `\+`, `-E` are non-standard extensions. POSIXly: `tab=$(printf '\t')` for the tab character.  `sed "s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/_/"`.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from your code, this should give you the desired output:

```
awk ' NR>1 { 
             printf( $1"_"$2 ); 
             for (i=3;i<NF;i++) printf("\t%s", $i); 
             printf("\n") 
           } 
      NR==1 { print } ' input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
awk '{ if(NR>1) { printf $1"_"$2; for(i=3;i<NF;i++) {printf "\t"$i } } print "" }' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small Python 3 script, which does the job. The underlying premise here is to read each line character by character use two variables - one which tracks whether the first-to-second column underscores have been written, and another - which tracks whether we're permitted to substitute space with underscore.

I've noticed from OP's input file format  that the second column is all numeric values. Thus, we can start with allowing for spaces to be substituted with underscores, but once we've written underscores and encountered a numeric character ( both conditions being true), we can turn off the `write_ok` variable, and the other spaces will be printed out as usual.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

def count_first_spaces(string):
    write_ok = True
    underscores_ok = False 

    for char in string:
        if char == " " and write_ok:
           print("_",end="")
           underscores_ok = True
           continue
        if underscores_ok  and char.isdigit():
           write_ok = False
        print(char,end="")
    print("") # add newline 

def main():
    if not os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]): sys.exit(1)
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            if line.startswith('#'): print(line.strip())
            else: count_first_spaces(line.strip()) 

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

And here's the test run:

```
$ ./add_underscore.py  input.txt                                                                                         
#CHROM  POS     REF     ALT     ../S101_sorted.bam      ../S102_sorted.bam          ../S105_sorted.bam      ../S107_sorted.bam      ../S113_sorted.bam      ../S114_sorted.bam      ../S115_sorted.bam      ../S
Aradu.A01_______296611  T       C       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T/C     T       T/C     T       T       T       T
Aradu.A01_______326689  T       C       T/C     T       T       T       T/C     T       T       T       T/C     T/C     T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T/C     T/C     T       T
Aradu.A01_______615910  T       G       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T
Aradu.A01_______661394  T       A       T       T       T       T       T       T/A     T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T
```

If you want that data to be saved to a different file, run it as `./add_underscore.py input.txt > output.txt`